# jQuery UI Drag and Drop causes bound click to trigger

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, click

I've got a UL of items using jQuery UI that I have drag and drop capable. However, I also need to be able to click on one of the items in the list and trigger off a little routine that adds a header line above one of the "li"s. The problem lies with the click on the drag and drop. I've tried to bind the click to a specific region of the li using a span but then I lose the index of the li. Here's my code, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
        var item_positions = $('#ml_organize').sortable('toArray');
  $('#ml_organize').sortable({
      placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
            cursor: 'pointer'
  });
  $('#ml_organize').disableSelection();
        $('#org_submit').click(function() {
            var item_positions = $('#ml_organize').sortable('toArray');
        });
        $('#ml_organize li').bind('click', function() {
            var rowNo = $(this).index();
            var newRow = "<li id=\'li" + rowNo + "\' class=\'ui-state-default\'><span class=\'icon ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick\' title=\'Remove header line\' alt=\'Remove header line\' onClick=\'removeMLRow(" + rowNo + ");\'></span><span class=\'note\'>HL</span><input class=\'header_line\' maxlength=\'75\' type=\'text\' name=\'hl_text[" + rowNo + "]\' id=\'hl_text" + rowNo + "\' /></li>";
            //alert(rowNo);
            $('#ml_organize li').eq(rowNo).before(newRow);
            $('#hl_text' + rowNo + '').focus(function() {
                $(this).css('background','#DDD');
            });
            $('#hl_text' + rowNo + '').blur(function() {
                $(this).css('background','#FFF');
            });
            $('#hl_text' + rowNo + '').focus();
            // renumber rows after insert
            $('#ml_organize li').slice(rowNo - 1).each(function() {
                var newID = 'li' + ($(this).index() + 1);
                $(this).attr('id',newID);
            });
            var item_positions = $('#ml_organize').sortable('toArray');
            // alert(item_positions);
        });
 });
    function removeMLRow(rowNo) {
        $('#ml_organize li').eq(rowNo).remove();
        // renumber rows after remove
        $('#ml_organize li').slice(rowNo).each(function() {
            var newID = 'li' + ($(this).index() + 1);
            $(this).attr('id',newID);
        });
        var item_positions = $('#ml_organize').sortable('toArray');
        //alert(item_positions);
    }
    $('#org_submit').button();
</script>
```

And here's the UL that it needs to manipulate:

```
<ul id="ml_organize">
   <li id="li1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">2</span><span class="org_partno">RFCH702</span><span class="org_desc">HEAVY HARDWARES(PAIR) 2.0" STGR</span></li>
    <li id="li2" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">2</span><span class="org_partno">FBM26CB</span><span class="org_desc">FLR BASE MLDINGX26" (CB VINYL)</span></li>
    <li id="li3" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">2</span><span class="org_partno">AFC2202DG</span><span class="org_desc">AUX CHANNEL, 4Â¿</span></li>
    <li id="li4" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">601343874</span><span class="org_desc">UNI-STRUT KIT - ED8C509-50 G9 EQUIVALENT</span></li>
    <li id="li5" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">4</span><span class="org_partno">ISS888</span><span class="org_desc">INSUL STRIP FOR BAYS-42" LONG</span></li>
    <li id="li6" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">4</span><span class="org_partno">ICS775</span><span class="org_desc">INSUL CABLE RACK 1.5"STG 7.75"</span></li>
    <li id="li7" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">2</span><span class="org_partno">CJB6302C</span><span class="org_desc">CLIP J-BOLT ASSM FOR 2"CR/FC</span></li>
    <li id="li8" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">TR53</span><span class="org_desc">5/8-11 THREADED ROD X  24.0"</span></li>
    <li id="li9" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">MAS-NTWKBAYKIT</span><span class="org_desc">FLOOR MNTG HARDWARE KIT (NTWK)</span></li>
    <li id="li10" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">ESD1080740001</span><span class="org_desc">ESD BANANA JACK</span></li>
    <li id="li11" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">ESDSTRAP</span><span class="org_desc">ADJ ELASTIC 63070</span></li>
    <li id="li12" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">ESDLABEL</span><span class="org_desc">GREEN .75" X 1.75" ESD LABEL</span></li>
    <li id="li13" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">SPT6224</span><span class="org_desc">SPLIT TUBE 5/8" X 24" GRAY</span></li>
    <li id="li14" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">SAF2502</span><span class="org_desc">FRAMING CLIP ASSM AUX CHNL 5/8</span></li>
    <li id="li15" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add header line" alt="Add header line"></span><span class="org_qty">1</span><span class="org_partno">T1523-0031-200</span><span class="org_desc">28 PR/24AWG SHLD, AMP 64-PIN FEMALE CONN</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the below solves the problem.

Note that I tried to clean up the code a bit as well, but it could still be a lot simpler. You don't need all the separate IDs for each LI, since you are using index() -- I removed them from the JS.

Couple of other points:

- If you will end up with hundreds or thousands of LIs, you should use event delegation rather than binding to click (event delegation might simplify this code further anyway).
- For elements handling clicks, it's usually nicer/better to use  rather than . You can then at least have them do something for people without JavaScript.

```
var mlo, item_positions, numAdded;
var disableAdd = false;
$(function() {
    mlo = $('#ml_organize');
    mlo
        .sortable({
            placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            start: function() {
                disableAdd = true;
            },
            stop: function() {
                setTimeout('disableAdd = false', 1000);
            }
        })
        .disableSelection();
        .find('li')
            .click(addMlRow);

    item_positions = mlo.sortable('toArray');

    $('#org_submit')
        .click(function() {
            item_positions = mlo.sortable('toArray');
        })
        .button();
});

function addMlRow() {
    if(disableAdd) return false;
    var that = $(this);
    var rowNo = that.index();
    numAdded++;
    $('<li id="new' + numAdded + '" class="ui-state-default"><span class="icon ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick" title="Remove header line"></span><span class="note">HL</span><input class="header_line" maxlength="75" type="text" name="hl_text[' + rowNo + ']" id="hl_text' + rowNo + '" /></li>')
        .insertBefore(that)
        .find('span.ui-icon-minusthick')
            .click(function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                item_positions = mlo.sortable('toArray');
            })
        .end()

        .find('input')
            .focus(function() {
                $(this).css('background','#DDD');
            })
            .blur(function() {
                $(this).css('background','#FFF');
            })
            .focus();

    item_positions = mlo.sortable('toArray');
}
```

Comment: BTW, I realise that the sortable('toArray') is useless now without the IDs, but in your example above, they are useless anyway, as you were renumbering the IDs to be consecutive, and then calling toArray. So functionally there's not much difference. If you can share a bit more about what you want to record, I can help.

Comment: I need to pass the array to an AJAX script so that the order can be saved and the "HEADER" lines (AddMLRow) can be placed in the correct positions in a db that includes the entire list of items. Does that clear it up at all?

Comment: BTW, I have exactly the same problem with your version. Although I do appreciate the clean-up and organization. As soon as I drop one of the li's, a header line appears above it. I'm sure it has to do with the fact that I click on the item I am dragging.

Comment: And I have no idea what event delegation is. I've only been using jQuery for 6 months and jQuery UI for a month.

Comment: OK, I edited it a little --I disabled the adding function until 1 second after the sort has completed. See if it works. I also added IDs back to the newly-added elements. Not sure you need to renumber the IDs though, you should get the ajax receiver to sort through them if you can.

Comment: The disable helps the appearance of the new row, THANKS!!!! However, I'm not quite syre what you mean by getting the AJAX receiver to do the renumbering without a proper array. I've decided to set the IDs as an array called pos[], that I think will help with that process. I'll let you know.